# VLC 3 can not play certain UDP streams

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, udp

I have a stream on this address `udp://@225.225.225.225:3002` and VLC 2.2.6 plays it perfectly, but on VLC 3.0.0 it can't be played. Are there any limitations for UDP on VLC 3.0.0? Are there any options to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> UDP mtu is limited in VLC 3.0 to 1316, you can set the packet size on OBS side by setting the address to "udp://1.2.3.4:4242?pkt_size=1316"

See here:
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=143484#p470409

I was having the same issue as you but the pkt_size parameter fixed it.  Hope this helps!